# How to get separate groups using one capturing group

Tags: regex

I have regex:

```
(?<=<start>\n)([^\n]+\n)+(?=<end>)
```

And the text:

```
<start>
123
456
789
<end>
```

Expected result is:

- Match 1: 123
- Match 2: 456
- Match 3: 789

Actual result is:

- Match 1: 789

How can I modify my regex to get expected result?

Comment: It looks like you want to get all captures from a group. What is your programming environment? It is not possible in many regex flavors, but it is built-in in Python `regex` module and .NET. See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##Lc3LCoMwEIXh/TxFcOMMFsHaO2oepLYgNqiLxDCZgn361ErX5/84/iPj7MoYJ@tnFsVmMAuIWUTVKkmSKkjH0kCxL@FwPMH5coXKuFezbmDXZgN5MB33I3KKuqr/hlDfWof3Z@seGVGGum7dZindqd8FgefJCSqb952XN5uABSmK8Qs).

Answer (score 2):

Using PCRE regex engines that support `\G`:

```sh
(?:<start>(?=[\s\S]*<end>)|(?<!\A)\G)\s\K(?!<end>)\S+
```

**Regex Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group
- `<start>`: Match `<start>`
- `(?=[\s\S]*?<end>)`: Assert that we have a line `<end>` ahead of us
- `|`: OR
- `(?<!\A)\G)`: Start from the end of the previous match
- `\s`: Match a whitespace
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `(?!<end>)`: Don't match `<end>`
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mg9vU3/3)

---

Alternatively, if you're using Javascript that now support dynamic length lookbehind like `.Net`:

```sh
(?<=<start>\n[^]*)^.+(?=[^]*<end>)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ql9gZZ/1)

Comment: pcre has case that it is not working with 4 chars: <start>
a123
b456
c789
<end>

Comment: @LyndaOlexandr: You can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/ddhDFU/2

Comment: @LyndaOlexandr: Did this work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you quantify a capture group, it only captures the last occurrence.

The trick is to put a capture group *around* the quantified group to get all of them.

```
(?<=<start>\n)((?:[^\n]+\n)+)(?=<end>)
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work. Still capture all the data between start and end as one group

Comment: That's what it's supposed to be. But it captures it all, not just the last one.

Comment: You can't get multiple groups in the result from a single group in the regexp.

Comment: using anubhava answer you can

Comment: That's multiple matches, not multiple groups ina single match.